# What is best way to pass data while navigating from one community page to another built on LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning, community, lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I have two community pages implemented on Lightning Web Component. I am looking for an efficient way to pass data while navigating from one community page to another made on LWC. I am using Navigation Mixin to navigate.

I already have one approach in mind that I can hack URL and send encrypted data, and decrypt at receiving end but every time I have to make the extra server call for decrypting as well as encrypting the data which is not efficient way to do this I believe.

Can you suggest an approach to handles this?

Comment: Can you provide some sort of direction as to the type of data you're hoping to pass?
In general, I'd say the url is the correct approach to transmitting data between web pages.

Comment: Does it have to be 2 pages? Can you create 1 lwc to act as a container for both of the other lwcs so you can pass the information via events?

Comment: Since you are using the Navigation Mixin you could use the state attribute to pass key value pairs to the destination page. You will need to define design time attributes to bind to those keys if you want to use those values in a component on the page.

Comment: @gNerb - Yes, it has to be two different pages.

Comment: @akiradev - Type should be standard__namedPage/comm__namedPage while navigating in community and there is no attribute called state. Related Doc - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type

Comment: @stackasaur  - consider 18 digit salesforce record id. Showing record id to end-users in URL could be a security threat. I could encrypt it but again it would solely depend on the public key and I'll need additional server call that I want to avoid.

Comment: @Mahesh,
You can and should control what records community users can access via sharing. What do you think will happen if they have the record id? You can control the generic pages and the object pages they have access to as well as profile access and community sharing sets. If you are passing the id to an apex class for record lookup/manipulation, consider using Name, or creating a new text field available as External ID if that would be better for you, both would be indexed fields.